# Cannot scp/rsync into live cd

Tags: networking, ssh, live-cd, rsync

I'm trying to scp into a box running 12.04 32bit livecd. The machines are connected to same switch & can ping each other just fine.

I use the usual args, eg-

```
scp -rp 'ubuntu@192.168.1.101:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/somefiletocopy.zip' .
```

but keep getting connection refused on port 22.

Its my understanding port 22 is open on livecd so I cannot figure out what the problem is..

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Please post the output of `lsof -Pni` on the machine running the livecd.  It sounds like you need to start SSH on that machine.

Comment: Did you install openssh-server?